# Is it possible to make a custom keyboard button in telegram bot for users to upload a file from local folder?

Tags: python-telegram-bot

Making a Telegram bot, that should give users an opportunity to upload files through a custom keybord button. However, the only option I see so far is just to save the file through a regular 'attach' button.

Suppose, it should be done somehow through CommandHandelr, but don't see how.

That's what I have now.

```
def upload_file(update, context):
    context.bot.get_file(update.message.document).download()
    with open('downloads/urls.xlsx', 'wb') as f:
         context.bot.get_file(update.message.document).download(out=f)
```

...

```
def main():
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(
        MessageHandler(Filters.document, upload_file))
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible, as such a button options is not listed in the [API docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).